# Android Manifest.xml not referencing correct integers.xml

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-gradle-plugin

I have two integers.xml files one for values and one for values-sw600dp. However no matter on which tablet I run the application it always takes the value stored in values/integers.xml.

```
<activity
    android:screenOrientation="@integer/orientation"
 .../>
```

The value is always taken from the values. It is important to note that I want the integer value to differ based on screen size.

Comment: Have you confirmed that at least one of the tablets you are using has a smallest width of 600dp in the orientation that you are using it?

Answer (score 0):

why not just do this in the Activity code as:

```
 if(getResources().getInteger(R.integer.orientation) == 0){
     setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
  }else{
     setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
  }
```

The Android Manifest does not change (immutable) its values once the APK is packaged, so using resources like this will not work as expected.

Comment: @JY2k this will not affect performance, your just telling your activity at run time how to orient itself with respect to the values in your screen specific folders. The Manifest file will not behave in this way